# Posting data from Jquery Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web

I have a simple jquery form which gets the input from user and posts the data to  another page and displays a success message.
But my problem is the data doesn't get posted to the other page, instead the error message gets popped up.

Here is my Jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#register").click(function () {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var cpassword = $("#cpassword").val();
    if (name == '' || email == '' || password == '' || cpassword == '') {
        alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
    } else if ((password.length) < 8) {
        alert("Password should atleast 8 character in length...!!!!!!");
    } else if (!(password).match(cpassword)) {
        alert("Your passwords don't match. Try again?");
    } else {

            $.ajax({

            type:"POST",
            url: "SignUp.aspx/register",    //trying to post to this url
            data: { firstName: name },

            success: function (msg) {
                alert("Success");        // Success message which should pop up if successful
            },
            error: alert("Failed")       //error message which should pop up if there is an error
        });
    }
});
});
```

Here is the code in signup.aspx page (code behind class):

```
         public string register(String firstName)
         {
            return "Success";            
         }
```

The url i have provided is correct there is no problem with that.
What might be the problem here ?

Also are there another methods to send data to another page?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Developer console will probably show you what server side error was raised.  Will probably be a good clue.

Comment: @KirkWoll No errors displayed

Comment: syntax is wrong for error handler, need to wrap alert in function and you need to prevent default form submit also. If those don't fix things need to inspect the actual request in netowrk tab of console

Comment: @charlietfl Ill try it and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("Success");        // Success message which should pop up if successful
        },
        error: alert("Failed")       //error message which should pop up if there is an error
    });
```

Should be:

```
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("Success");        // Success message which should pop up if successful
        },
        error: function(){alert("Failed")}       //error message which should pop up if there is an error
    });
```

You could have additional errors though.

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax call is not correctly formatted.  It should be:

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "SignUp.aspx/register",    //trying to post to this url
        data: { firstName: name })
        .done(function(data)
         {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
         })
        .success(function (msg) {
            alert("Success");        // Success message which should pop up if successful
        })
        .fail(function(err){
            alert("Failed");       //error message which should pop up if there is an error
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting contentType option of your ajax request,

```
contentType:'application/x-www-urlencoded; UTF-8',
```

I hope that solves your problem.

Comment: that's the default in $.ajax api...setting it as default won't do anything